# Rainbow table with Bash

Tags: bash, openssl

I am looking at looping through 2 files to create a rainbow table in bash and I am having trouble with the syntax. I have 2 text files, 1 `filename` which has a list of commonly used passwords, and `saltList` which has the salt for a small list of passwords. Currently, the script will execute but never stops (I ran it for about 3-4 hrs yesterday). Am I doing this correctly? I check the rainbowCracker.txt file and it has values in it `$1$fa7eb627$NRWF9wGqdr4rjHmrxmxI80` but it never seems to stop.

```
        saltList=$(tr ' ' '\n' < ${saltFile})

        for line in $filename; do
                for salt in $saltList; do
                        openssl passwd -1 -salt $salt $line >> rainowbowCracker.txt
                done
        done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to loop over lines in bash is with the while construct:

Try this:

```
while read a; do
  while read b; do 
     echo $a $b
  done < saltlist.txt
done < passwords.txt
```

The other approach is to read everything first into memory. This works if the files are small enough:

```
salts=($(< salts.txt))

for s in ${salts[@]}; do
  echo $s
done
```

Comment: Would I replace `echo $a $b` with `openssl passwd -1 -salt $salt $line >> rainowbowCracker.txt`?

Comment: Yes. Give it a try ;-)

Comment: That worked! Are `for` loops not commonly used in bash?

Comment: They are used. But the point with the while-loop construct is that it "streams" over the lines of a file and handles newlines gracefully thanks to the read builtin. More modern languages have support for iterators that let you for-loop over lines in an memory efficient way. Bash is a really primitive language. There's typically nothing elegant about it :-D